# How to set WinJS.UI.ListView as a required control?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am working on a Windows 8 app using the winjs library, html5, jquery ,etc.

I am trying to set the selection of at least one item inside a ListView object as required, is this possible?

I know you can do this through html5 for html5 controls with the reserved word "required" but I have no idea how to do the same with the winjs library in place.

Any help¿

Comment: That applies to HTML form elements, not WinJS controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the same way as you can with a form element, but you can check the selection count.

```
function someEventHandler(e) {
    if (myListView.winControl.selection.count() >= 1) {
        // proceed
    }
}
```

Optional: If it is important to make it work with other HTML validation, you can check into the `setCustomValidity` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772949(v=vs.85).aspx) and `checkValidity` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772948(v=vs.85).aspx) functions.  They won't work out of the box with `ListView`, but you can, for example, update a hidden field when the `ListView` selection changes and set custom validation rules on that field.